# Error AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQL database details:

```
import sqlalchemy as sch
from config import Config

db_uri = os.environ["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] + os.environ["DB_NAME"]
```

in the env file I have these

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://*****:*****@instance-amazonaws.com:3306/'
DB_NAME = 'DB_NAME'
```

Now

```
db_engine = extrac_db.create_engine(Config.db_uri)
db_connection = db_engine.connect()
```

When I try this query:

```
db_connection.execute("select count(*) from table")
query_result = db_connection.fetchall()
```

It gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

What is the problem here!!!?

Comment: Why would you need a FetchAll when the result of a count query will always be a single row in the resultset?

Comment: You may also want to place an alias on the count column so its easier to access like `select count(*) as tot from table`

Comment: fetchall() is available in a cursor class - not the connection class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess:

```py
query = db_connection.execute("select count(*) from table")
query_result = query.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work with SQLAlchemy

```
import import sqlalchemy as sch
import pprint

with db_engine.begin() as conn:
    qry = sch.text("select count(*) from table")
    resultset = conn.execute(qry)
    results_as_dict = resultset.mappings().all()
    pprint(results_as_dict)
```